# Skip Searching For Floppy (Drive A: ) When Restoring Norton Ghost Image?

Tags: floppy, norton-ghost

I am trying to restore a Norton Ghost image of Windows XP, but at some point, it searches for every drive (A,B,C,D,..). I don't have a floppy(A:) in my PC anymore, but on the screen is a command prompt waiting for me to introduce a floppy drive. How can I can skip this step?

I know this is possible to do, because someone did it for previously, but I don't know exactly what the command is to skip the search.

Comment: Please, read FAQ before posting next time, thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: What version of Ghost? How are you restoring - via a bootable disc/GhostCasting/other?